# Numeros perfectos en bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

dispongo de un código mayor al que le tengo que implementar una "calculadora" de números perfectos.
Por el momento he intentado esto, pero el programa no se ejecuta, me da un error en el for. Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
#!/bin/bash

suma=0

for ((x=1; x<$num; x++))
do
if ($num%x==0)
suma+=x
done

if($suma == $num)
echo El número es perfecto 
else
echo El número no es perfecto
```

Gracias y un saludo

Comment: Por favor ve a [edit] y añade el error que encuentras para que otros puedan darte respuestas útiles.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El error en tu código es que estás tratando de usar el for loop de Bash de manera incorrecta. El for loop de Bash espera que se le pase una lista de valores, pero en tu caso estás tratando de pasarle una expresión matemática en lugar de una lista.

En lugar de usar un for loop, puedes usar un while loop para iterar sobre los números desde 1 hasta el número que deseas verificar. Dentro del while loop, puedes verificar si el número es divisible entre el número que estás verificando y si lo es, agregarlo a la suma. Una vez que hayas verificado todos los números hasta el número que deseas verificar, puedes comprobar si la suma es igual al número. Si lo es, entonces el número es perfecto.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo podrías implementar esto en tu código:

```
#!/bin/bash

suma=0

# Iterar sobre los números desde 1 hasta el número que deseas verificar
i=1
while [ $i -lt $num ]
do
  # Verificar si el número es divisible entre el número que estamos verificando
  if [ $(($num % $i)) -eq 0 ]
  then
    # Si es divisible, agregarlo a la suma
    suma=$(($suma + $i))
  fi

  # Incrementar el contador del while loop
  i=$(($i + 1))
done

# Verificar si la suma es igual al número
if [ $suma -eq $num ]
then
  echo El número es perfecto
else
  echo El número no es perfecto
fi
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema con tu código. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Usar chatGPT sin citar la fuente es considerado [Plagio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plagio). Relacionado: [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes), [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned). Tu cuenta puede ser suspendida por este motivo.

Comment: Gracias por su información. Comprendo que es importante citar la fuente cuando se utiliza chatGPT y tomaré esto en cuenta en el futuro para evitar cualquier problema con mi cuenta. Aprecio su ayuda en señalar esto.

Comment: No, simplemente no puedes usar chatGPT en ninguno de los sitios de Stackoverflow. Lamentablemente la política no ha sido escrita aún, pero de momento está prohibido. Si lo usas y se detecta, tal como ha sucedido en esta publicación, tu cuenta también será suspendida, aunque cites la fuente.

Comment: @quifar07 usar ChatGPT para contestar preguntas es causal de baneo. Simplemente, no estas dando la atribucion necesaria al autor de la respuesta, y ChatGPT no es el autor.

Comment: No inventen! Yo no conocía esa cosa de chatGPT! 
Sólo para fines de investigacion, si en esta publicación respondo copiando y pegando lo que me dio de respuesta, Me va a avisar a mi tambien sobre el uso de esta herramienta?

Comment: @Cuauhtli la herramienta no es permitida para respuestas en [es.so] (o cualquier versión de [so]), si se detecta que la usas para responder preguntas, serás reportado por plagio. :/ (Relacionado: [cheatGPT (chatGPT) nos ha alcanzado en SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes) y [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned))

Comment: Justo lo estaba leyendolos y disfrutandolos <3 Sólo quisiera saber si hay algún lugar donde pueda probar esa herramienta aqui en SO? Sólo quiero que me llegue la notificación de que uso chatGPT

Answer (score 1):

Más allá de señalar errores en el código, el título "**Números perfectos en Bash**" es por sí mismo interesante y por lo tanto, vale la pena considerar otros abordajes al mismo problema.

Todo *divisor propio* de un número entero es, o un factor primo de éste, o bien, el producto de **algunos** de sus factores primos. El comando `factor` del paquete `coreutils` devuelve los factores primos de un número entero. Basta entonces considerar los **distintos productos** de estos factores primos, sumarlos y hacer el test requerido.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Validación de la entrada: debe ser entero mayor que 1
[[ "$1" =~ ^[0-9]+$ && "$1" -gt 1 ]] || { echo "Ingrese número entero mayor que 1"; exit 2; }

# Función power_set: devuelve todos los posibles subconjuntos de un conjunto
# Ver: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11667/348372
power_set() { [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && echo || (shift; power_set "$@") | while read r; do 
    printf '%s %s\n%s\n' "$1" "$r" "$r"; done; }

#Suma de todos los divisores del entero dado (excluyendo 1 e incluyendo el mismo número)
SUMA_DIVISORES=$(power_set $(factor $1 | cut -d' ' -f2-) | tr ' ' '*' | sed 's/*$/*1/' \
                 | bc -ql | sort -n | uniq | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s}')

# En el test debemos excluir/restar el input e incluir/sumar el 1
[[ $1 -eq $(( SUMA_DIVISORES-$1+1 )) ]] && echo "Es perfecto" || echo "No es perfecto"
```

#### Ejemplo:

```bash
for I in {1..30}; do is-perfect.sh $I; done | nl
     1  Ingrese número entero mayor que 1
     2  No es perfecto
     3  No es perfecto
     4  No es perfecto
     5  No es perfecto
     6  Es perfecto
     7  No es perfecto
     8  No es perfecto
     9  No es perfecto
    10  No es perfecto
    11  No es perfecto
    12  No es perfecto
    13  No es perfecto
    14  No es perfecto
    15  No es perfecto
    16  No es perfecto
    17  No es perfecto
    18  No es perfecto
    19  No es perfecto
    20  No es perfecto
    21  No es perfecto
    22  No es perfecto
    23  No es perfecto
    24  No es perfecto
    25  No es perfecto
    26  No es perfecto
    27  No es perfecto
    28  Es perfecto
    29  No es perfecto
    30  No es perfecto
```

#### Eficiencia:

```bash
time ./is-perfect.sh 33550336
Es perfecto

real    0m0.163s
user    0m0.242s
sys     0m0.117s
```